# Pyqt can't shrink qPushButtons width even though text has lots more space

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I have a pyqt window with some layouts and a QTabWidget (built in Qt Designer).

I want to be able to shrink this window width-wise and height-wise, to the point that the set of buttons called "O" and "S" can be basically squares, nice and neatly shaped around the text.

But I hit a hard stop when the QPushButtons are still very wide and tall.

The QPushButtons are in a QGridLayout. I want them to stretch to the width of the grid. Meaning I actually want the QGridLayout to shrink. When I delete the buttons from the layout it can shrink very small, so it is ultimately the buttons.

I have another script that modifies the code later so I can alter it through code, but it seems I should be able to set this up straight in Qt Designer. Any answers would be most helpful if they addressed both what wrong about my settings in QtD and what the code would be.

Thanks so much!

[Pyqt Window Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GmhCF8WSnYDmEX5srYjmCgqtnsH2TbCR/view?usp=sharing)

Minimum example (full window is more complex):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(207, 161)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.masterWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.masterWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.masterWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.masterWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.masterWidget.setObjectName("masterWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.masterWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.masterLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.masterLayout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.masterLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.masterLayout.setObjectName("masterLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.masterWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane { border: 0; }")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_characters = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab_characters.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab_characters.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab_characters.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.tab_characters.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tab_characters.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tab_characters.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tab_characters.setObjectName("tab_characters")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_characters)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.char_perAssetLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.char_perAssetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.char_perAssetLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.char_perAssetLayout.setObjectName("char_perAssetLayout")
        self.char_masterLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.char_masterLayout.setContentsMargins(2, -1, 2, -1)
        self.char_masterLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.char_masterLayout.setObjectName("char_masterLayout")
        self.char_masterSkeletonOpenButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_characters)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.char_masterSkeletonOpenButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.char_masterSkeletonOpenButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.char_masterSkeletonOpenButton.setObjectName("char_masterSkeletonOpenButton")
        self.char_masterLayout.addWidget(self.char_masterSkeletonOpenButton, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.char_masterSkeletonSaveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_characters)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.char_masterSkeletonSaveButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.char_masterSkeletonSaveButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.char_masterSkeletonSaveButton.setObjectName("char_masterSkeletonSaveButton")
        self.char_masterLayout.addWidget(self.char_masterSkeletonSaveButton, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.char_masterGeoOpenButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_characters)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.char_masterGeoOpenButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.char_masterGeoOpenButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.char_masterGeoOpenButton.setObjectName("char_masterGeoOpenButton")
        self.char_masterLayout.addWidget(self.char_masterGeoOpenButton, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.char_masterHeaderLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_characters)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.char_masterHeaderLabel.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.char_masterHeaderLabel.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.char_masterHeaderLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.char_masterHeaderLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.char_masterHeaderLabel.setObjectName("char_masterHeaderLabel")
        self.char_masterLayout.addWidget(self.char_masterHeaderLabel, 0, 2, 1, 2)
        self.char_masterGeoSaveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_characters)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.char_masterGeoSaveButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.char_masterGeoSaveButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.char_masterGeoSaveButton.setObjectName("char_masterGeoSaveButton")
        self.char_masterLayout.addWidget(self.char_masterGeoSaveButton, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.char_perAssetLayout.addLayout(self.char_masterLayout)
        self.char_perAssetLayout.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.char_perAssetLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_characters, "")
        self.Props = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Props.setObjectName("Props")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Props, "")
        self.masterLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.masterLayout.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.masterLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.masterWidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 207, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Project File Management"))
        self.char_masterSkeletonOpenButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "O"))
        self.char_masterSkeletonSaveButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "S"))
        self.char_masterGeoOpenButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "O"))
        self.char_masterHeaderLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Master"))
        self.char_masterGeoSaveButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "S"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_characters), _translate("MainWindow", "C"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Props), _translate("MainWindow", "P"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT:

the .ui file associated with this py code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>207</width>
    <height>161</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="baseSize">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="cursor">
   <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Project File Management</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="masterWidget">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="masterLayout" stretch="1">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="baseSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="layoutDirection">
         <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">QTabWidget::pane { border: 0; }</string>
        </property>
        <property name="tabPosition">
         <enum>QTabWidget::West</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="tabShape">
         <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="elideMode">
         <enum>Qt::ElideNone</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="documentMode">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="tabsClosable">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="movable">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="tabBarAutoHide">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_characters">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="baseSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="layoutDirection">
          <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="autoFillBackground">
          <bool>false</bool>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true"/>
         </property>
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Characters</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="1">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="char_perAssetLayout" stretch="1">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeConstraint">
             <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
            </property>
            <item>
             <layout class="QGridLayout" name="char_masterLayout" rowstretch="0,0,0">
              <property name="leftMargin">
               <number>2</number>
              </property>
              <property name="rightMargin">
               <number>2</number>
              </property>
              <property name="spacing">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <item row="2" column="2">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterSkeletonOpenButton">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>O</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="2" column="3">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterSkeletonSaveButton">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>S</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="1" column="2">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterGeoOpenButton">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>O</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="0" column="2" colspan="2">
               <widget class="QLabel" name="char_masterHeaderLabel">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>0</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Master</string>
                </property>
                <property name="alignment">
                 <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="1" column="3">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterGeoSaveButton">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>S</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="Props">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Tab 2</string>
         </attribute>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>207</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

a modified version to remove a bunch of the size policy stuff (but still doesn't scale down fully):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="cursor">
   <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Project File Management</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="masterWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="masterLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
        <property name="layoutDirection">
         <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="tabPosition">
         <enum>QTabWidget::West</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="tabShape">
         <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="elideMode">
         <enum>Qt::ElideNone</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="documentMode">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="tabsClosable">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="movable">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="tabBarAutoHide">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_characters">
         <property name="layoutDirection">
          <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
         </property>
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>C</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="1">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="char_perAssetLayout">
            <item>
             <layout class="QGridLayout" name="char_masterLayout">
              <item row="2" column="2">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterSkeletonOpenButton">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>O</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="2" column="3">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterSkeletonSaveButton">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>S</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="1" column="2">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterGeoOpenButton">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>O</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="0" column="2" colspan="2">
               <widget class="QLabel" name="char_masterHeaderLabel">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Master</string>
                </property>
                <property name="alignment">
                 <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item row="1" column="3">
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="char_masterGeoSaveButton">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>S</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="Props">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>P</string>
         </attribute>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>207</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: It seems like you've tried to do lots of things that override the default behavior (especially, size policies). Can you please provide the `ui` file instead of the generated pyuic file?

Comment: Original Sample from above:
[ORIGINAL_UI_FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pc-uJQEiqbSExPoqpI8978JMP3V-l7NB/view?usp=sharing)
With the size policies removed on as many things as I can spot but still not working:
[FILE_WITHOUT_SIZE_POLICIES](https://drive.google.com/file/d/196xzTe3ouIle7wdgZOoZhWqtJmJOHZGO/view?usp=sharing)
Thats a good point @musicamante . I was trying so many to just see if any triggered anything but couldnt get it to shrink with any size policies. Here's a version also with the size policy overrides killed.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the contents of those ui files: questions should always be self-contained and not rely on external resources.

Comment: @musicamante not a problem. i've used stack overflow as a reference for quite a while but haven't needed to post before. wasn't sure of best practices.